# How to delimiter text file

Tags: vb.net, file, delimiter

In my application, I need to Read delimited text file in vb.net

> 2016/05/15 21:59:13,739 [7] INFO - Login.User_Aut - o03dx1n Unknown -
>   Login: KST028

```
with:
Day        2016/05/15
Time       21:59:13,739
LogType    [7] INFO
MethodName Login.User_Aut
SessionID  o03dx1n Unknown
LoginID    Login: KST028
Message
```

Here is my code so far.

```
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Dim filepath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim inputstream As New IO.StreamReader(filepath)
        Dim newstr() As String
        Dim Day As String
        Dim Time As String
        Dim LogType As String
        Dim MethodName As String
        Dim SessionID As String
        Dim LoginID As String
        Dim Message As String
        Do While inputstream.Peek <> -1

            newstr = inputstream.ReadLine().Split(" ")

            Day = newstr(0)
            Time = newstr(1)
            LogType = newstr(2)
            MethodName = newstr(3)
            SessionID = newstr(4)
            LoginID = newstr(5)
            Message = newstr(6)


            Me.LogListView.Items.Add(Day)
            Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Time)
            Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(LogType)
            Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(MethodName)
            Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(SessionID)
            Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(LoginID)
            Me.LogListView.Items.Item(LogListView.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(Message)
        Loop

        inputstream.Close()
    End Sub
```

this code is wrong because :
day and time is correct but logtype,session id,loginid,message of columns is wrong

Comment: Shouldn't `LogType = newstr(2)` be `LogType = newstr(2) & " " & newstr(3)`?  And then other fields should be adjusted (and concatenated) accordingly.

Comment: I sure hope it's a tab delimiter and not a space. If it's a space then the only way that works is if all fields have fixed width. I suspect that is what you have. In which case you need to read based on count of chars.

Comment: No competent developer would use space as a delimiter without a qualifier. This has to be fixed width.

Comment: thank you but logtype only fixed

Comment: I think you want to split on the hyphen ("-"c) you would still need to substring the 1st part, but that should be relatively simple as you could substring out the date and split the remainder of that on the colon

Comment: Cross-post on ja.SO https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36064/19110

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would break this down using the hyphen as the delimiter. By doing this you recieve 4 parts (5 if message is included and separated by a hyphen)
the 0th element of the array contains everything up to the first hyphen and needs to be broken down to use each of its parts separately. I've commented the code which should help you understand better what each section is doing.

```
    'these would need adjusted to fit your stream
    Dim inputstream As String = "2016/05/15 21:59:13,739 [7] INFO - Login.User_Aut - o03dx1n Unknown - Login: KST028"
    'this produces an array of 4 elements 
    Dim parts() As String = inputstream.Split("-"c)
    'element 0 of the array needs to be broken down into its
    'proper substrings
    Day = parts(0).Substring(0, 10).Trim
    Time = parts(0).Substring(12, parts(0).IndexOf("[") - 12).Trim
    LogType = parts(0).Substring(parts(0).IndexOf("[") - 1).Trim
    'these 3 elements of the array are retrieved fromt the split on the delimiter
    MethodName = parts(1).Trim
    SessionID = parts(2).Trim
    LoginID = parts(3).Trim
    'display in console window. Here you would assign these variables to 
    'your listview instead.
    Debug.Print(String.Format("Day={0}{7}Time={1}{7}LogType={2}{7}Method={3}{7}Session={4}{7}Login={5}{7}Message={6}", Day, Time, LogType, MethodName, SessionID, LoginID, Message, Environment.NewLine))
End Sub
```

Again, this doesn't really handle Message as your string didn't contain one but from this you should be able to work out how to manage it. I wasn't sure if message was something from the string or something entered later